# JLabel wont change color twice

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, colors, jlabel

I have the following code:

```
   public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 private static final Color TRANSP_WHITE = new Color(new Float(1), new Float(1), new Float(1), new Float(0.5)); 
 private static final Color TRANSP_RED = new Color(new Float(1), new Float(0), new Float(0), new Float(0.1));
 private static final Color[] COLORS = new Color[]{ TRANSP_RED, TRANSP_WHITE};
 private int index = 0;

 private JLabel label;
 private JButton button; 
 public Test(){
  super();

  setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  label = new JLabel("hello world");
  label.setOpaque(true);
  label.setBackground(TRANSP_WHITE);

  getContentPane().add(label);

  button = new JButton("Click Me");
  button.addActionListener(this);

  getContentPane().add(button);

  pack();
  setVisible(true);
 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if(e.getSource().equals(button)){
   label.setBackground(COLORS[index % (COLORS.length - 1)]);
index++;
      }
     }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Test();
 }
    }
```

When I run it I get the label with the `TRANSP_WHITE` background and then when I click the button this color changes to `TRANSP_RED` but when I click it again I see no change in color. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It should be done like that

```
label = new JLabel("hello world"){
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
         //draw background
         Color old=g.getColor();
         g.setColor(getBackground());
         g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
         g.setColor(old);
         super.paintComponent(g);
     }
};
label.setOpaque(false); // your component is not opaque!
```

Comment: This is correct as I am using translucent colors so Swing will not paint the components under it before it provides the JLabel

Answer (score 3):

Well, what were you expecting to happen?

```
label.setBackground(COLORS[index % (COLORS.length - 1)]);
```

The index variable is hard coded to 0.  and COLORS.length -1 is essentially a constant.  So every time you click your setting the background to COLORS[0];

If you change your action method to the following you'll get the results you are looking for:

```
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if(e.getSource().equals(button)){
   label.setBackground(COLORS[index % COLORS.length]);
   index++;
  }
 }
```

First: The modulo operator will always return a value between 0 and one less than the value passed to it. So

```
index % COLORS.length
```

Will always return a value between 0 and COLORS.length -1.

Second:  You were forgetting to increment index after every call.

Comment: See my newly added actionPerformed method.

Answer (score 2):

Hey! You forgot to increment index. In this expression:

```
label.setBackground(COLORS[index % (COLORS.length - 1)]);
```

`index % (COLORS.length - 1)` is always 0.

BTW. you don't have to use `new Float(1)` when creating `Color`. `1F` should work too.

Comment: cool, I've edited code to include index++ but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you have to use

`label.setBackground(COLORS[index % (COLORS.length)]);

index++;`